# how to generate new line for each word found following a specific character in scripts and add first word from the line in front of new line

Tags: linux, arrays, shell

I have a file with following lines. would like to write a script

```
driver: keeps, ask  
cartoon: drake, mast, tent
```

how do I achieve the following result

```
driver: keeps
driver: ask
cartoon: drake
cartoon: mast
cartoon: tent
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)  Tip - `awk` can probably do this for you in no time.

Comment: here again (cat test |tr "," "\n" |tr -d " ") is the command I tried

Comment: this would be a good code golf question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an awk command that works here:

```
awk -F'[:, ]+' 'OFS=": " { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started:

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1, $i}}' f1
driver: keeps,
driver: ask
cartoon: drake,
cartoon: mast,
cartoon: tent**
```

Next step is to use `gsub` to tidy things prior to displaying them or to play with the imput field selector...